# Adding the values from an object to an array of objects without overriding existing key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

How do you go from this:

```
var array = [{key: [3]}, {key1: [3]}, {key1: [3]}]
var object = {key1: [3], key2: [3]};
```

to this:

```
{key: [3], key1: [9], key2: [3]}
```

All "key" are a userIds like "LQVjUacPgK" as seen in the obj example below.

[N] = is an array of N objects each of which has about 10 key value pairs within.

```
N = {obj, obj, obj};

obj = {_account: "JDQEPxoy3ktZRP9VEzAMtXLa7rXXedhQ4bARq"
_id: "oQER3vznDwikxm1wdLzJFdVjKL6XomcORMxDL"
amount: 170
category: Array[2]
category_id: "21003000"
date: "2015-06-09"Object
type: Object
userId: "LQVjUacPgK"}
```

Right now I'm doing this:

```
var test = _.reduce(_.flatten(array.concat([object])),function(a,b){
     return _.extend(a, b);
       });
    }
};
```

and getting this result instead:

```
console.log(test)//{key: [3], key1: [3], key2: [3]}
```

To be clear, the issue is that key1 has different values between all of the objects.  I'd like to keep the values from both so that **key1: [9]**.

Comment: I'm confused about what [N] represents. Could you expand the input sample to be more representative of your actual problem?

Comment: @Jack I broke open the data structure more for you so you could see N.

Comment: So, instead of an array with a single number element it's an array of objects? And should the result be an array with a single object element, an array of multiple object elements ... etc

Comment: The result should be an object with key value pairs where the values are an array of objects.  The method that I tried (and am working in parallel to your help on) is returning a result where some of the values are overwritten as underscore tends to do when combining arrays and I need to have key value pairs where values are added to one another when there are redundant keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an underscore answer, but basically I wouldn't use a reduce operation for this and instead do a simple for-each:

```js
var array = [{key: [3]}, {key1: [3]}, {key1: [3]}]
var object = {key1: [3], key2: [3]};

array.forEach(function(current) {
  Object.keys(current).forEach(function(name) {
//        object[name] = [((object[name] || [])[0] || 0) + current[name][0]];
      object[name] = (object[name] || []).concat(current[name]);
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(object)); // {"key1":[3,3,3],"key2":[3],"key":[3]}
```

Comment: Trying it now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It works when I stringify on my console and in the code snippet but when I make your answer a var and console.log it is undefined.  Is this right or am I doing something wrong?  I need to pass this object on to something else and it's not clear to me what to do with this.

Comment: I just tried to pass it on and it provides the wrong result. I tried it with dummy data as shown it works correctly.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @rashadb The problem with your question is that we have no idea what those data structures *mean*, so we have to make assumptions .. please provide an example in which my answer doesn't work or explain what kind of data is stored in your variables.

Comment: I add some detail about key (UserId) and [N] which is itself an array of objects.  Let me know what else I might add to help.

Comment: @rashadb I've made a slight adjustment in how the result is formulated; let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Jack's answer (also non-underscore), but it creates a new object, it doesn't modify the existing *object* Object:

```
var array = [{key: [3]}, {key1: [3]}, {key1: [3]}]
var object = {key1: [3], key2: [3]};

var x = array.concat([object]).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  Object.keys(curr).forEach(function(key){
    if (prev.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      prev[key][0] += curr[key][0];
    } else {
      prev[key] = curr[key];
    }
  });
  return prev;
},{});

console.log(JSON.stringify(x));  // {"key":[3],"key1":[9],"key2":[3]}
```